# Handle dicts/json with nested elements

Tags: python, json, dictionary

**tldr;** Python 3.8. I want to work with a ‘clean’ dict with no empty entries to generate an adequate json output. For this case I need a function which handles it and supported a nested structure. This solution should be generic enough to work with n nested objects.

I want to work with a ‘clean’ dict with no empty entries to generate an adequate json output in Python 3.8. Internally I use a dict to store everything which will later dump to the disk. I know that `{}` is a valid json (and `{“data”:{}}` also) but IMHO it’s not clean. Parsing this kind of json only shows that nothing useful is stored.

So the idea is to avoid this unclean json by checking key/values which are added or removed to the json. This should support nested values to, like `{"os":{"network":{"ip":"”localhost”"}}}` (any depth), usable in an OOP style, e.g. `def handleElement(key,value,**sections)`. If the value is empty, it should ‘clean up’ the dict removing every section if the section has no content.

After hours of searching I found neither a python build-in way to do this or some extensions or solutions on the web. I tried a lot by myself, but I found no way to iterate smooth over the dict and work on it. Because the calling syntax for dicts with nested elements is `dict[][][]…` I found no way to iterate over the dict and call the nested elements without coding every depth by hand.

Do you have any good idea? If you need more information or something is unclear, please ask!

Examples:

```
dict before: {}

call handleElement(“ip”,”localhost”, [os, network])
dic after: {“os”: {“network”: {“ip”: “localhost”}}

call handleElement (“ip”,””, [os, network])
dic after: {}

call handleElement (“ip”,”localhost”, [os, network])
call handleElement (“subnetmask”,”full”, [os, network])
dic after: {“os”: {“network”: {“ip”: “localhost”, “subnetmask”:”full”}}

call handleElement (“ip”,””, [os, network])
dic after: {“os”: {“network”: { “subnetmask”:”full”}}
```

Comment: Processing multi-level nested structures is a perfect case for recursive solution.

Comment: stack overflow wont usually just write your code for you ... instead you need to get started and when you get stuck with a logical problem come ask for help ... i would start with `def handleElement(key,value,parents_list)`

Comment: @Błotosmętek: I totally agree, but I found no way to make a recusive way if I need the depth level for dict access.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I know and I never expect a full solution, but I stuck at the start with the problems mentioned in the question and need some good ideas here; do you have some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need a recursive approache, what you need is

1. when the value is not empty
2. build the path of the parents
3. set the `key/value` mapping

```
def handle_element(item, key, value, parent_list):
    if value:                              # 1.
        for parent in parent_list:
            item.setdefault(parent, {})    # 2. add the parent with empty dict
            item = item[parent]            # go further in the dict
        item[key] = value                  # 3.
```

## [`CODE DEMO`](https://repl.it/repls/VastOffshoreWaterfall)

Comment: Nice, never heard about the dict.setdefault()! This is a good approach for adding an element. Found some description on https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Comment: I will accept this as an answer. It doesn't solve the whole question, but it got me on the right track. A similar procedure can be used to delete the entries. First iterated to the key / value, then check whether they are need to get deleted and then goes up, which can be solved recursively.